# Assign the labor sector to a list according to the Occupation / workplace and position of the employee

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this file with occupation or work places names and the position of the worker and based in that data I need to add a column with the "Labor sector" ex: if the position is Medic or the work place / occupation is doctor then the Labor sector it would be Health.

I tried this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hospital",D2)), "Health","")
```

But this would only work for one labor sector at the time and there are plenty of it on the file and I have to determine the labor sector to 4000 contacts.

So, is there a way to do this more efficiently with VBA, or something else?

Example [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16w_WUeEBGVMNqJyoqTKyylQgEgPmhjxi)!

Comment: I would use a separate sheet where I have a column with all these possible positions, and another column with the desired sector for each of these positions. The you can use a `VLOOKUP` to match them. No `VBA` required.

Comment: @DarXyde makes a good suggestion, without knocking it, I would also consider INDEX() with MATCH()... Search on here, there are examples of both doing what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo @DarXyde and @Solar Mike: vlookup is the way to go. You'll have to create a second set of data that maps the answers you want, but it sounds like it will be worth the time investment.

Index/match is in some ways more powerful, but also harder to use.

[simple explanation](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s165/using_vlookup_in_microsoft_excel.htm) 
[more complex](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) 
[more complex](https://spreadsheeto.com/vlookup/)